# Split a tbody element for specific tr childs using plain JavaScript (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, dom

this could be an example of an input table:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr1InOtherTbody"><td>a1</td><td>a2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr1"><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
            <tr id="tr2"><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr>
            <tr id="tr3"><td>31</td><td>32</td></tr>
            <tr id="tr4"><td>41</td><td>42</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr2InOtherTbody"><td>b1</td><td>b2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

with startId = "tr2"; endId ="tr3". The table needs to be converted to:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr1InOtherTbody"><td>a1</td><td>a2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr1"><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody id="tr2tr3">
            <tr id="tr2"><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr>
            <tr id="tr3"><td>31</td><td>32</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr4"><td>41</td><td>42</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr2InOtherTbody"><td>b1</td><td>b2</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

how can this be achieved? thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far? Stackoverflow is not for implementing your code..

Comment: it would be a very specific explanation and the answer wouldn't help another coders. In short, I'm making a TinyMCE plugin that tags the user selection with dynamic attributes: I already have done when user selects any content outside a table (or including a table) and when selects content inside a single row. I'm facing real trouble when user selects content inside two or more rows. I did a comprehensive research and I couldn't find so far a generic walkthrough to achieve something similar: split tbody content. That's why I ask.

Comment: If it wouldn't help other coders, then is offtopic too. For a broad question, a broad answer. Save the cells in some variables, then empty the innerHTML of the table and rewrite it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to tackle this might be to iterate over the rows in the proper tbody and just build a replacement block of html.

```js
function reformat(startId, endId){
  var startEl = document.getElementById(startId);
  var endEl = document.getElementById(endId);
  
  // ---------------------------
  // make sure we can do something useful
  // ---------------------------
  if (!startEl || !endEl || startEl.parentNode != endEl.parentNode){ console.log("wrong"); return; }
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // find all tr elements of the proper tbody
  // ---------------------------
  var rows = startEl.parentNode.querySelectorAll("tr");
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // construct a new block of html from the rows of interest
  // ---------------------------
  var newHtml = Array.from(rows).reduce(function(html, item){
    if (item.id === startId) {
      html += "</tbody><tbody id=\"" + startId + endId + "\">";
    }

    html += item.outerHTML;

    if (item.id === endId) {
      html += "</tbody><tbody>";
    }

    return html;
  }, "<tbody>");

  newHtml += "</tbody>";
  // ---------------------------

  // ---------------------------
  // overwrite the original tbody with our new html
  // ---------------------------
  startEl.parentNode.outerHTML = newHtml;
  // ---------------------------
}

reformat("tr2","tr3");
```

```css
tbody:nth-child(1) { background-color: #aaa; }
tbody:nth-child(2) { background-color: #f88; }
tbody:nth-child(3) { background-color: #8f8; }
tbody:nth-child(4) { background-color: #88f; }
tbody:nth-child(5) { background-color: #aaa; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr1InOtherTbody"><td>a1</td><td>a2</td></tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr1"><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr id="tr2"><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr>
    <tr id="tr3"><td>31</td><td>32</td></tr>
    <tr id="tr4"><td>41</td><td>42</td></tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr2InOtherTbody"><td>b1</td><td>b2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```